# Creating a new User Account Spring data rest framework

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I have been trying to create a new user for my webApp. I am using spring-data-rest. At the front end, a prospective user submits his information and then the app is supposed to create back-end information. The codes are as below.

User.java

```
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private String address; 
    //getters and setters
}
```

UserRepository.java

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "user", path = "user")
public interface UserRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<User, Long>{

}
```

Is it okay to have view as below? Do I need to worry about id? It is supposed to be generated by backend, so it does not make any sense to put id field in view.

registration.html

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:sec="https://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Welcome, Enter The User Details</h3>
     <form:form action="#" th:action="@{/user}" th:object="${user}" method="post">
        <div><label> User Name : <input type="text" th:field="*{username}"> </label></div>
        <div><label> Password: <input type="password" th:field="*{password}"/> </label></div>
        <div><label> Email: <input type="email" th:field="*{email}"/> </label></div>
        <div><label> Address: <input type="text" th:field="*{address}"/> </label></div>
        <div><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></div>
    </form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about thymeleaf, but answer for your question is **it is ok.**

You don't need to worry about id in view, it is automatically created by your dao framework. By `@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)`

You can use this kind of thing since it's a Spring MVC

```
<form:hidden path="id"/>
```